# Binning in Pandas Cut

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas cut to bin certain values in ranges according to a column. I am using user defined bins i.e the ranges are being passed as array.

```
df['Range'] = pd.cut(df.TOTAL, bins=[0,100,200,300,400,450,500,600,700,800,900,1000,2000])
```

However the values I have are ranging till 100000. This restricts the values to 2000 as an upper limit, and I am losing values greater than 2000. I want to keep an interal for greater than 2000. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: and np.inf?   `pd.cut(df.TOTAL, bins=[0,100,200,300,400,450,500,600,700,800,900,1000,2000,np.inf])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's add `np.inf` to end of your bin list:

```
pd.cut(df.TOTAL, bins=[0,100,200,300,400,450,500,600,700,800,900,1000,2000,np.inf])
```